# Modify the gremlin Query to add a new field along with existing one

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I am new to `Gremlin` struggling modify the query to get the appropriate result.
I have a query that gives the `depth` of the graph. The query is as below:

```
g.withSack(0)
  .V('company_1')
  .repeat(
    outE('HAS_SHRHLDING_PC_TO')
    .sack(sum).by(constant(1))
    .inV()
    .simplePath())
    .until(not(outE()))
  .sack()
  .max()
  .aggregate('x')
  .fold()
  .V(company_1)
  .repeat(
    outE('HAS_VOTING_PC_TO')
    .sack(sum).by(constant(1))
    .inV()
    .simplePath())
    .until(not(outE()))
  .sack()
  .max()
  .aggregate('x')
  .cap('x')
  .unfold()
  .max()
```

The output is return in number. The output is as below:

```
4
```

I am trying to modify this query to get the output as key-value pair, rather than only value as I have to add more one key and value to the output.

I want to retrieve the `company_number` that is passed in input along with the `depth`.

sample expected output:

```
{'company_number': 'company_1', 'depth': 4}
```

I tried to use `project` was unsuccessful in achieving the desired result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you might do it:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.withSack(0).V(1).as('start').
......1>   repeat(out().simplePath().sack(sum).by(constant(1))).
......2>     emit(__.not(outE())). 
......3>   dedup(). 
......4>   select('start').
......5>   project('v','depth').
......6>     by().
......7>     by(sack()).
......8>   order().by('depth',desc).
......9>   limit(1)
==>[v:v[1],depth:2]
```

I avoid using `max()` so that the path history isn't lost and we can `select('start')` to get back to the start vertex. At that point, it's easy to `project()` and then order by the "depth" to get the deepest one.

To take this a step further, if you supplied multiple start vertices you would find that the query is grabbing the deepest point only. In other words, the `order().limit()` is doing that globally for all start vertices which is great if you just want the deepest path. If you want the deepest path per start vertex you need to use `map()`:

```
gremlin> g.withSack(0).V(1,4).as('start').
......1>   map(
......2>   repeat(out().simplePath().sack(sum).by(constant(1))).
......3>     emit(__.not(outE())).
......4>   dedup().
......5>   select('start').
......6>   project('v','depth').
......7>     by().
......8>     by(sack()).
......9>   order().by('depth',desc).
.....10>   limit(1))  
==>[v:v[1],depth:2]
==>[v:v[4],depth:1]
```

Comment: Hi @stephen, thanks you for the answer. I am able to do the above changes and get the desired output. There is one problem, the output comes as below:
```{'company_number': v[company_1], 'depth': 3}```
But the expectation is as below:
```{'company_number': 'company_1', 'depth': 3}```
Is there a way to remove the `v` and `[]`?

Comment: the `project()` takes a `by()` for each key you specify. for "v" i did `by()` which just produces the vertex as it is and makes it the value for the "v" key in the `Map`. You could do `by(id)` instead to use the vertex identifier or do `by('pkey')` to extract a property value named "pkey" from your vertex instead.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the cause of the problem. I tried  `by(id)`. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Added one more example/point to consider in the answer.